# PHP function to filter .csv file for display

Tags: php, csv

I've searched other questions to get me this far, but I'm missing a key element to make my code work.

The csv file is formatted as:

```
job;customer;location;tech;side
Ex(12345;company;floor 1;John;Auto)
```

Below is my current function:

```
function readCSV($csvFile,$side){
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile,'r');
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024,';');
}
fclose($file_handle);
return $line_of_text;
}
```

I want the function to only load the records that match the $side parm. (Example: Drive side, or Auto side)

Thanks in advance, I'm new to whole gathering data from csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`side` is the fifth column (index 4) of the CSV, so just check if it equals `$side` and if so add it to your array:

```
function readCSV($csvFile,$side){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile,'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        //save temp line
        $line = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024,';');
        //compare temp line forth column and if matches add line to array
        if ($line[4] == $side) {
            $line_of_text[] = $line;
        }
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!